# DRF: Serializer Group By Model Field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want my api to return `Account` objects grouped by the `account_type` field in the model. I want to do this so that the grouped accounts are easier to access in my JS code. This is what is returned now:

```
[{
  "id": 6,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Credit Card 1",
  "account_type": "credit card",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:44.288654Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:44.288842Z"
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Savings 1",
  "account_type": "savings",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:22.122226Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:22.122283Z"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Checking 1",
  "account_type": "checking",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:28.580268Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:28.580305Z"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Savings 2",
  "account_type": "savings",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:59:57.156837Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:59:57.156875Z"
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Savings 3",
  "account_type": "savings",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:12.873799Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:12.873846Z"
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "owner": 1,
  "account_name": "Credit Card 2",
  "account_type": "credit card",
  "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:55.921586Z",
  "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:55.921613Z"
}]
```

And I'd like it to return something like this:

```
{
  "credit card": [
    {   "id": 6,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Credit Card 1",
        "account_type": "credit card",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:44.288654Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:44.288842Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Credit Card 2",
        "account_type": "credit card",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:55.921586Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:55.921613Z"
    }  
  ],
  "savings": [
    {
        "id": 11,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Savings 1",
        "account_type": "savings",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:22.122226Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:22.122283Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Savings 2",
        "account_type": "savings",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:59:57.156837Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:59:57.156875Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Savings 3",
        "account_type": "savings",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:12.873799Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T03:00:12.873846Z"
    }
  ],
  "checking": [
    {
        "id": 5,
        "owner": 1,
        "account_name": "Checking 1",
        "account_type": "checking",
        "created_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:28.580268Z",
        "modified_time": "2019-07-18T02:57:28.580305Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

Model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    CHECKING = 'checking'
    CREDIT_CARD = 'credit card'
    SAVINGS = 'savings'

    ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (CHECKING, 'Checking'),
        (CREDIT_CARD, 'Credit Card'),
        (SAVINGS, 'Savings'),
    ]

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    account_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        null=False
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=128,
        null=False,
        choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE_CHOICES
    )
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer:

```
class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id',
                  'owner',
                  'account_name',
                  'account_type',
                  'created_time',
                  'modified_time')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        account = Account.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return account
```

Edit: Adding my views.py because I'm curious if that's the issue.

```
class AccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Account.objects.all().order_by('account_name')
    # serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    serializer_class = AccountByTypeSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        page = self.paginate_queryset(self.queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):

        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data,
                        status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                        headers=headers)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance,
                                         data=request.data,
                                         partial=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Why not do `Model.objects.all().order_by("account_type")` in your view?

Comment: My goal is to be able to access these more easily in my UI code without having to iterate over the whole response. Sorting by `account_type` does collect them, however it doesn't make it any easier to pull out only a specific account_type for rendering in the UI.

Comment: Why don't you want to use javascript for this reshaping? Just reshape after fetching the data from the api. Seems cleaner and simpler than creating a custom api endpoint.

Comment: I'd just rather do this kind of thing server-side. Is that bad practice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have only a limited amount of account type choices, you can use `SerializerMethodField`s, like this:

```
class AccountByTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    checking = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    savings = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    credit_card = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def _build_account_list(account_type):
        accounts = Account.objects.filter(account_type=account_type)
        serializer = AccountSerializer(accounts, many=True)
        return serializer.data

    def get_savings(self, obj):
        return self._build_account_list(Account.SAVINGS)

    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('checking', 'savings', 'credit_card')
```

I suggest you to use `credit_card` instead of `credit card`, but if you really need to use the latter, just override `to_representation`.

Comment: I think I was looking for something more dynamic. However, you're right about the limited choices. This list could grow in the future, but I don't foresee it becoming unmanageable. I'll give this a try.

Comment: What about adding `.distinct()` like `accounts = Account.objects.filter(account_type=account_type).distinct()` ?

Comment: Adding `.distinct()` doesn't resolve the issue with duplicates

Comment: Maybe my view is the issue. I've addd that to the original post.

Comment: This works not that I've changed `many=True` to `many=False` in my `list` method in the view