# Group by field in serializer for DRF

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to group all my articles by category for DRF. I have the following my serializers.py:

```
class GroupPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sound = serializers.FileField(required=False)
    image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
    category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())
    url = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, required=False, default=None, allow_blank=True)
    english = serializers.CharField(source="base", required=False, allow_blank=True)
    per_language = PerLanguageCondensedSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)
    target = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    base = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Page
        fields = ['per_language', 'base', 'target', 'english', 'date', "json", "id", "category", "title", "image", "sound", "url", "slug"]
```

And this in my views.py:

```
class GroupedArticleListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Page.objects.select_related().all()
    serializer_class = GroupPageSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter)
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    ordering_fields = ['date']
    filter_class = ArticleMultiValue
```

I have been trying writing a list serializer class, I've been trying to write various "to_representation" functions, etc.

All I want is so that all of my results are grouped by category, as such:

```
"business": [
{article1...},
{article2...}
],
"technology": [
{article3...},
{article8...},
],
```

etc

How do I do this?

Comment: [Might be related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260171/drf-serializer-group-by-model-field) [Might be related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092167/django-rest-framework-group-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to change the main model of your ViewSet, or create another ViewSet:

```
class CategoryListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Category.objects.select_related().all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
```

Serializers:

```
 class PageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        sound = serializers.FileField(required=False)
        image = Base64ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)
        category = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=Category.objects.all())
        english = serializers.CharField(source="base", required=False, allow_blank=True)
        per_language = PerLanguageCondensedSerializer(many=True, required=False, read_only=True)
        target = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
        base = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    
        class Meta:
            model = Page
            fields = ['per_language', 'base', 'target', 'english', 'date', "json", "id", "category", "title", "image", "sound", "url", "slug"]

    class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            your_related_page_field_name = PageSerializer(many=True)
            class Meta:
                model = Page
                fields = '__all__'
```